# Mobile fixed position social share widget position change when scrolling

Tags: css

I use CSS and HTML based social sharing plugin for my WordPress site. It's natively not supporting fixed position. Then I used the following additional CSS to make it sticky only on the mobile devices. I think `max-width: 767px` is ok for mobile devices (if I'm wrong please correct).

It works on my tested device, but when I'm scrolling page this widget position slightly changes and again it comes to the fixed position.

How do I fix this position change? For better understanding, I added gif at the end of the post.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .socialsharing {
  position: fixed;
  top: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7.5%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-7.5%);
  transform: translateY(-7.5%);
  display: flex;
  width: auto-flow;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing position:fixed; or use position:absolute

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer will help you to fix your problem, there are a lot of ways to handles fix footer issues definitely but I prefer this kind of class which is really simple to understand because you set a div or body to 100% of viewport height and then margin-top: auto and bottom:0; will fix the stack in footer all the time problem. Good Luck

```css
.h-100{
  height : 100vh;
}

.button {
 background-color: orange;
}

/* I added class here to show how its working in Code Snippet, you don't need to do this part of css*/
  .socialsharing {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: auto !important;
    display: block !important
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
  }

/*end of extra Css*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .socialsharing {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: auto !important;
    display: block !important
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="h-100">
  <div class="bodyContent">
    <h3> Social Media in Footer </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="socialsharing">
      <input type="button" value="StackOverflow" class="button"/>
  </div>
<div>
```